# Can these slides be looped?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Just worked on a simple *div* slider with arrows. The code works just fine, except, when I navigate to the left or right, it stops at the last item.

Right now, *when a user clicks the left arrow to the last div slide, it stops*. Also, *when a user clicks the right arrow to the last div slide, it stops*.

*What I am trying to achieve is **when I navigate to the left or right, the slider should continue in a loop***. That is, without ending at the last item.

For instance, *when a user clicks the right arrow after reaching 8, **the next number should be 1, click again 2 follows, click again 3 follows,*** and so on. Likewise, *when a user clicks the left arrow after reaching 1, **the next number should be 8, click again 7 follows, click again 6 follows,*** and so on.

```js
let buttonLeft = document.getElementById('slide_left')
let buttonRight = document.getElementById('slide_right')

let container = document.getElementById('slider')

buttonLeft.addEventListener('click', function() {
  container.scrollLeft -= 90
})

buttonRight.addEventListener('click', function() {
  container.scrollLeft += 90
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #555;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
}

div#slide_wrapper {
  width: 440px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: fit-content;
}

div#slider {
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  height: fit-content;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.thumbnail {
  min-width: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

div.thumbnail:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: darkturquoise;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: goldenrod;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: salmon;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: lawngreen;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: sienna;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(7) {
  background-color: bisque;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(8) {
  background-color: navy;
}

div#slide_wrapper>button {
  height: fit-content;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

div#slide_wrapper>button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide_wrapper">
  <button id="slide_left" class="slide_arrow">&#10094;</button>
  <div id="slider">
    <div class="thumbnail active">1</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">2</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">3</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">4</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">5</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">6</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">7</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">8</div>
  </div>
  <button id="slide_right" class="slide_arrow">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: So it shoud be posible to see 6,7,8,1 and the next one 7,8,1,2 ... Is that right ?
or you just want when it's in position 5,6,7,8 and you click "right arrow" to return to 1,2,3,4 ?

Comment: @angel.bonev yes... I guess... if I got your abstract logic correctly.

Comment: I'll post an answer for the second logic if it's not the correct one we will commented there

Comment: @angel.bonev I think I would want it to basically "continue in the same order" infinitely. Instead of just jumping to 1,2,3,4 after reaching 8 or jumping to 5,6,7,8 after reaching 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on exactly what effect you want, but for the simple case illustrated you can just remove the first (or last, depending on which direction you are going) element and put it to the end (or beginning) of the set of thumbnails.

That makes things a bit more responsive too as you don't have to fix the widths in px terms if you don't want to as they don't have to be remembered in order to move the elements.

```js
const buttonLeft = document.getElementById('slide_left')
const buttonRight = document.getElementById('slide_right')

const container = document.getElementById('slider');

buttonLeft.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const last = document.querySelector('#slider > :last-child');
  last.remove();
  container.prepend(last);
})

buttonRight.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const first = document.querySelector('#slider > :first-child');
  first.remove();
  container.append(first);
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #555;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
}

div#slide_wrapper {
  width: 440px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: fit-content;
}

div#slider {
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  height: fit-content;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.thumbnail {
  min-width: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

div.thumbnail:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

div.thumbnail.c1 {
  background-color: darkturquoise;
}

div.thumbnail.c2 {
  background-color: goldenrod;
}

div.thumbnail.c3 {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

div.thumbnail.c4 {
  background-color: salmon;
}

div.thumbnail.c5 {
  background-color: lawngreen;
}

div.thumbnail.c6 {
  background-color: sienna;
}

div.thumbnail.c7 {
  background-color: bisque;
}

div.thumbnail.c8 {
  background-color: navy;
}

div#slide_wrapper>button {
  height: fit-content;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

div#slide_wrapper>button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide_wrapper">
  <button id="slide_left" class="slide_arrow">&#10094;</button>
  <div id="slider">
    <div class="thumbnail c1 active">1</div>
    <div class="thumbnail c2">2</div>
    <div class="thumbnail c3">3</div>
    <div class="thumbnail c4">4</div>
    <div class="thumbnail c5">5</div>
    <div class="thumbnail c6">6</div>
    <div class="thumbnail c7">7</div>
    <div class="thumbnail c8">8</div>
  </div>
  <button id="slide_right" class="slide_arrow">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's overall a better way to render the data dynamically, only have 4 containers whose values change as you click on the left and right arrows, instead of having a long scrollable div. That becomes more difficult to maintain especially if you're trying to implement wrap-around feature.

So I changed the logic of how you render the data onto the screen. Instead of having as many divs in the container as there are data, hiding them and scrolling through the div as buttons are clicked, I made it so that there are always 4 (or as many as you want) containers and their values are changed as you press the buttons from a variable (and the containers stay in the same position and never move).

A good learning experience would be to change the shape of the data to something like:

```js
const data = [
  {
    value: 1,
    color: goldenrod
  }, {
    value: 2,
    color: rebeccapurple
  }...
]
```

and get the colors to apply to the divs when you press the buttons inside `render` function by [setting styles of an HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style#setting_styles).

Hope this helps.

```js
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
let curPos = 0;

let buttonLeft = document.getElementById('slide_left')
let buttonRight = document.getElementById('slide_right')

let container = document.getElementById('slider')

const render = (curPos) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < container.children.length; i++) {
    container.children[i].innerText = data[wrapPos(curPos + i)];
  }
}

const calculatePos = (newPos) => {
  if (newPos >= data.length) {
    curPos = 0;
    return curPos;
  }
  if (newPos < 0) {
    curPos = data.length - 1;
    return curPos;
  }

  curPos = newPos;
  return curPos;
}

const wrapPos = (pos) => {
  if(pos >= data.length) return pos - data.length;
  return pos;
}

buttonLeft.addEventListener('click', function() {
  render(calculatePos(curPos - 1))
})

buttonRight.addEventListener('click', function() {
  render(calculatePos(curPos + 1))
})

render(curPos);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #555;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
}

div#slide_wrapper {
  width: 440px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: fit-content;
}

div#slider {
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  height: fit-content;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.thumbnail {
  min-width: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

div.thumbnail:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: darkturquoise;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: goldenrod;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: salmon;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: lawngreen;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: sienna;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(7) {
  background-color: bisque;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(8) {
  background-color: navy;
}

div#slide_wrapper>button {
  height: fit-content;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

div#slide_wrapper>button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide_wrapper">
  <button id="slide_left" class="slide_arrow">&#10094;</button>
  <div id="slider">
    <div class="thumbnail active"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
  </div>
  <button id="slide_right" class="slide_arrow">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried using this in my text editor. Not sure what I'm doing wrong as it's not displaying any number and it's not working.

Comment: could you update your post with the code and let me know?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach with `removeChild` (remove the first/last elements) and `insertAdjacentHTML` (insert the last/first elements).

```js
let buttonLeft = document.getElementById('slide_left');
let buttonRight = document.getElementById('slide_right');
let container = document.getElementById('slider');

let containerMaxLeft = container.scrollWidth - container.clientWidth;
buttonLeft.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let nextPos = container.scrollLeft - 90;
  if (nextPos < 0) {
     const lastChild = container.lastElementChild
    container.removeChild(lastChild)
    container.insertAdjacentHTML(
        "afterbegin",
        lastChild.outerHTML
    );
  } else {
    container.scrollLeft = nextPos;
  }
});

buttonRight.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let nextPos = container.scrollLeft + 90;
  if (nextPos > containerMaxLeft) {
    const firstChild = container.firstElementChild
    container.removeChild(firstChild)
    container.insertAdjacentHTML(
        "beforeend",
        firstChild.outerHTML
    );
  } else {
    container.scrollLeft = nextPos;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #555;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
}

div#slide_wrapper {
  width: 440px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: fit-content;
}

div#slider {
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  height: fit-content;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.thumbnail {
  min-width: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

div.thumbnail:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

div.thumbnail {
  background-color: darkturquoise;
}

div#slide_wrapper>button {
  height: fit-content;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

div#slide_wrapper>button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide_wrapper">
  <button id="slide_left" class="slide_arrow">&#10094;</button>
  <div id="slider">
    <div class="thumbnail active">1</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">2</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">3</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">4</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">5</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">6</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">7</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">8</div>
  </div>
  <button id="slide_right" class="slide_arrow">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

*Note: Colors are not applied correctly because the first element will become the last element, so the colors will be messed up with the changed element orders.*

Comment: I am speechless. Could go on to ask you what planet you come from. Thank you, Sir. I'm grateful.

Comment: You're welcome!~ You will become an alien someday as well haha @Matrion